# Are "How does X work" titles banned?

Tags: support

Is Stack Overflow enforcing 'magic words' now? Is there a patch note for this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: tl;dr it's a very poorly thought out title filter that triggers on certain words if the whole thing is under 40 characters

Comment: @JohnMontgomery So this isn't new... surprised it never triggered before.

Comment: The title is intentionally phrased in simple terms for searchability; the [revised title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66538595/10133797) isn't that much richer.